# type 'int' error in python. largest sum of (len) digits in integer n function

Tags: python

The question is to define a function using (n,len) that finds len consecutive digits in n with the largest sum, and if len is greater than the digits in n print invalid input and -1. 
I've done it but I keep getting type 'int' error. Can someone help me find my mistake? This is what i've written.

```
def max_len_sum(n, length):
    input_as_str = str(n)
    input_len = len(input_as_str)
    max_sum = 0
    max_int = 0

    if length > input_len:
        print "invalid input"
        return -1

    for i in range(0, input_len - length + 1):
        test_int = int(input_as_str[i:i + length - 1])
        test_sum = sum(i for i in test_int)
        if test_sum > max_sum:
            max_int = test_int

    print max_int
    return max_int
```

Comment: So, what exactly do you mean by "type 'int' error"?

Comment: sorry that was unclear it says: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: its in the secound line of your for loop, test_int is an int and you cannot iterate it.

Comment: i think to remove your problem, write something like this: test_sum = sum(int(i) for i in str(test_int)), this casts test_int back into a string and you can iterate every digit of it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
test_int=int(input_as_str[i:i+length-1])
test_sum=sum(i for i in test_int)
...
```

test_int is not iterable as it's type is `int`

If a variable is not iterable that means it can't be divided into smaller units. For example `list`, `tuple`, `str` types are iterable, `int` is not. For `list` and `tuple` the smaller unit is an element, for a `str` it's a character.

So, you probably can solve your error by doing something like this:

```
test_int=input_as_str[i:i+length-1]
test_sum=sum(int(i) for i in test_int)
```

@shuiyu has some suggestions. I recommend to read his answer and comments.

Comment: sorry i'm new to this and i've been fiddling with those two lines quite a bit. what does that mean it's not interable? and how should i fix it?

Comment: `test_int=input_as_str[i:i+length-1]` should be `test_int=input_as_str[i:i+length]`, or just got `len-1` digits

Comment: @shuiyu nope, his loop is `for i in range(0, input_len - length + 1)`

Comment: @Crystal `for i in range(0, input_len - length + 1)` calculate the first digit position of the next n digits int, and the `test_int=input_as_str[i:i+length]` get the right n digits int, while `input_as_str[i:i+length-1]` just get a n-1 digits. They are two things.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not trying to solve the "type 'int' error", but give a more efficient solution. It is not necessary to calculate the sum of `every n digits`.

For example, n is 123456 and len = 3

The first int is 123 and sum is 6

The next int is 234 and sum is 9, which can be calculated by 6 - 1 + 4, while 1 is the first digit of last int and the last digit of this int

The next int is 345 and sum is 12, which can be calculated by 9 - 2 + 5

By this solution, the max int can be retrieve by just one loop, which lead to time complexity O(n), and eliminate the inner loop `sum(i for i in test_int)`, which lead to time complexity O(n^2)

```
from itertools import islice
def another_max_len_sum(n, length):
    input_as_str = str(n)
    input_len = len(input_as_str)
    max_sum = 0
    max_int = 0

    if length > input_len:
        print "invalid input"
        return -1

    max_sum = sum(int(i) for i in islice(input_as_str, 0, length))
    max_i = 0
    for i in range(0, input_len - length):
        test_sum = max_sum - int(input_as_str[i]) + int(input_as_str[i+length])
        #test_sum = sum(int(i) for i in test_int)
        if test_sum > max_sum:
            max_i = i+1

    max_int = int(input_as_str[max_i:max_i+length])
    print max_int
    return max_int
```